# Issue with dbplyr::spread() on tbl_sql

Tags: r, dbplyr

This is a specific issue of the following dev version of dbplyr:

devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dbplyr", ref = devtools::github_pull(72)) developed by @edgararuiz

It seems to me that the spread function doesn't work properly...

```
df_sample <- tribble(~group1, ~group2, ~group3, ~identifier, ~value, 
                      8, 24, 6, 'mt_0', 
                      12, 18, 24, 6, 'mt_1', 4)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
df_db <- copy_to(con, df_sample, 'df_sample')
```

I obtained an incorrect result with the following command.  There should've been only one row of data after spread.

```
df_db %>% spread(identifier, value)
```

[image]

The result is correct if the original data is downloaded to local memory.

```
df_db %>% collect() %>% spread(identifier, value)
```

[image]

Anybody has any idea?  Also, I am not sure how I can reach @edgarauiz.  Appreciate it if somebody could let him know.  Thanks!

Comment: Leave a note on the [Github issues page](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues)

Comment: I'd love to.  For some reason I can't create an account on GitHub.  The account creation process is always stuck at step 1: Create a personal account...

Answer (score 1):

I just port this over to GitHub.  Will let the author handle this.