# How to spread tbl_dbi and tbl_sql data without downloading to local memory

Tags: r, sqlite, tidyr, r-dbi, dbplyr

I am working with large datasets and tidyr's `spread` usually gives me error messages suggesting `failure to obtain memory`to perform the operation.

Therefore, I have been exploring [dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html). However, as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750199/issue-with-dbplyrspread-on-tbl-sql), and also shown below, `dbplyr::spread()` does not work.

My question here is whether there is another way to accomplish what `tidyr::spread` does while working with `tbl_dbi`  and `tbl_sql` data without downloading to local memory.

Using sample data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750199/issue-with-dbplyrspread-on-tbl-sql), below I present what I get and what I would like to do and get.

**#sample tbl_dbi and tbl_sql data**

```
df_sample <- tribble(~group1, ~group2, ~group3, ~identifier, ~value, 
                      8, 24, 6, 'mt_0', 
                      12, 18, 24, 6, 'mt_1', 4)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
df_db <- copy_to(con, df_sample, 'df_sample')
```

**#attempting to spread tbl_dbi and tbl_sql without downloading to local memory**

```
//this does not work

df_db %>% spread(identifier, value)

Error in UseMethod("spread_") : 
  no applicable method for 'spread_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

**#attempting to spread tbl_dbi and tbl_sql after downloading to local memory**

```
//this spreads the data but the output is in memory
//I would like to keep the output as 'tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', and 'tbl_lazy'

df_db %<>% collect() %>% spread(identifier, value)

class(df_db)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your use case? What do the key and value columns contain? An iteration over columns usually can be replaced with a grouped operation on the corresponding long-form dataset, this should work pretty well on the database.

Comment: Thanks, @krlmlr. `key=identifier, value=value`. Normal data. Just large. Could you kindly share an example of your thoughts as an answer?

Comment: What are the operations you want to perform on the "wide" dataset?

Comment: @Krantz, have you found solution to this problem? Any way spread on the database yet?